# How can I make a generic class convertible in type?

Tags: c#, generics

If I have a generic class:

```
class Collection < G >  {
    public G[] stuff
}
```

and I have two other classes, one of which can convert to the other (though more complex than this!)

```
class Foo {
    public Foo( int i ) { myInt = i; }
    public int myInt;
}
class Bar {
    public Bar( float f ) { myFloat = f; }
    public float myFloat;
    public static implicit operator Foo( Bar bar ) {
        return new Foo( Math.Ceil(bar.myFloat) );
    }
}
```

And I have collections of both:

```
Collection < G >  fooCollection = new Collection < Foo > ();
Collection < G >  barCollection = new Collection < Bar > ();
```

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
Collection < G > fooCollection2 = barCollection.Convert( typeof(Foo) );
```

How would I go about that?

***EDIT: this is for Unity, which I believe is still on .NET 2.0.***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Collection<Foo> fooCollection = new Collection<Foo> { stuff = barCollection.stuff.Select(bar => (Foo)bar).ToArray() };
```

If you'd like, you can add extension method to Collection:

```
public static Collection<TResult> Select<TResult, T>(this Collection<T> c, Func<T, TResult> projection)
{
   return new Collection<TResult> { stuff = c.stuff.Select(x => projection(x)).ToArray() };
}
```

And then you can call it like so:

```
Collection<Foo> fooCollection2 = barCollection.Select(bar => (Foo)bar);
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm using Unity, which I believe still is on .NET 2.0 - is this feature available in that?

Comment: Wow, not sure I understand the second piece of code at all. If that code is viable in .NET 2.0 I'll have a go and try to understand it better.

Comment: I should say this is .NET 3.5 and above.

Comment: Lambdas (and extension methods) are a feature of C# 3.0, not .Net, so you should be able to use them with a newer compiler targeting the older runtime. LINQ is new in .Net 3.5, but you can use [LINQBridge](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqbridge.aspx) to get it on .Net 2.0.

Comment: This from Unity Answers: "Sure, lambda expressions and LINQ can be used in Unity. Used it alot even on Android and iOS"
So maybe I'm going to be okay :) Thanks all!